# SQLite INSERT with SELECT

Tags: sqlite, insert, insert-into

I have a  problem with INSERT Query. I want to insert some fixed values as a name but as well some calculated values.
A simple example:

```
INSERT INTO Players 
VALUES('Name', 10.0, SELECT COUNT(*) AS Amount FROM Stack7 WHERE Name LIKE '%Name%', 1.0)
```

Table Players:

```
CREATE TABLE `Players` (
    `Name`  TEXT,
    `Points`    REAL,
    `Games` REAL,
    `Result`    REAL
)
```

Compiler says:
near "SELECT": syntax error:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your select in Brackets:

```
INSERT INTO Players 
VALUES('Name', 
       10.0, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Amount FROM Stack7 WHERE Name LIKE '%Name%'), 
       1.0);
```

In this way the compiler knows where the one value defined by your select statement starts and where it ends. And you are able to use a comma (`,`) inside your brackets if needed.

Comment: Unbelievable that it was so simple! I've been working on it for around 2 hours. Is there a possibility to Insert a value calculated basing on the 2 previous ones?
Imagine another SELECTreturning e.g. a column Points in place of 10.0. Could we place something similar to (Columns/Amount) instead of  the last inserted value (1.0)? In a form above it is not working- "no such column: Points: " it doesn't see these selects.